# What does it mean that the subgroup is equal to $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H,K\leq G$.

$[H,K]$ symbolizes the subgroup of $G$ that is generated by all the $[h,k]$ with $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.

I want to show that $H\subseteq C_G(K)$ iff $[H,K]=1$.

$$$$

We have that $$C_G(K)=\{g\in G\mid gk=kg, \forall k\in K\}$$

$$$$

What exactly does it mean that the subgroup $[H,K]$ is equal to $1$ ? That it is the identity?

Comment: It is the trivial subgroup.  $1=\{e\}$.

Answer (score 5):

It is standard notation for the trivial subgroup (the subgroup whose only element is the idenity).